# Migrate a Jackson JsonDeserializer from 1.9 to 2.0

Tags: json, parsing, jackson

I have to migrate the following code from Jackson 1.9 to 2.0

```
public class ObjectIdDeserializer extends JsonDeserializer<ObjectId> {
    @Override
    public ObjectId deserialize(JsonParser jp, DeserializationContext context) {
        JsonNode oid = jp.readValueAsTree().get("$oid");
        return new ObjectId(oid.getTextValue());
    }
}
```

Because the return type of `readValueAsTree()` has change from `JsonNode` to `TreeNode` I'm not able anymore to access to its value. I've tried `hasCurrentToken()`, `nextToken()` and others strange methods like those without finding a way to access gracefully to the tree nodes. The `get` method that I was using rely on a `map`, so it does not need any iteration.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [`ObjectMapper`](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-databind/blob/master/src/main/java/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/ObjectMapper.java#L1429) class from Jackson :

```
public <T extends TreeNode> T readTree(JsonParser jp) throws IOException, JsonProcessingException
{
    /* ... */
    JsonNode n = (JsonNode) _readValue(cfg, jp, JSON_NODE_TYPE);
    if (n == null) {
        n = getNodeFactory().nullNode();
    }
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    T result = (T) n;
    return result;
}
```

`readTree` method is called by `readValueAsTree` method, and as `JsonNode` implements `TreeNode`, just cast the `TreeNode` object returned to an `JsonNode` object and you'll get the result that you expect !

```
@Override
public ObjectId deserialize(JsonParser jp, DeserializationContext context) {
    JsonNode oid = ((JsonNode)jp.readValueAsTree()).get("$oid");
    return new ObjectId(oid.asText());
}
```

Comment: Exactly. The reason additional `TreeNode` type was added was to reduce size of core jar: `JsonNode` base type is quite big, and core does not really need to do what it has. This does require upcast for specific case when going from core type (like `JsonParser` or `JsonGenerator`) however.

Comment: One more note: you should even need explicit cast in this case: due to generic method parameter, simple assignment to `JsonNode` should work without cast (cast being inferred by compiler, added under the hood)/